# How to set up google OAuth 2.0 on a server without shell access?

Tags: google-oauth

I have a web host that does not provide shell access and I have to provide 'Sign in with google' on my site. Is there a way to set up OAuth 2.0 without installing anything on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Use Sign in with google (javascript).